# MS Access - Count of multiple values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a this Table in MS Access:

```
Table1
ID  EMP     ROLE    ASSESS
1   JOE     Weld    4
2   TOM     Weld    4
3   JIM     Ship    4
4   PAT     Ship    3
5   JAY     Weld    4
6   TIM     Ship    4
```

"ROLE" is short text and "ASSESS" is a number field. "ASSESS" is assessing employees' roles on a scale of 1-4. I want to collect and total assessments that are "4" for each role.

Returning something like:

```
ROLE    TOTAL
Weld    3
Ship    2
```

I however have around 100 different roles that I am needing to do this with. Is there a way with SQL or a combination of query and macro to make this work? I am at a loss.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `where` clause to filter just the the `assess`es that are 4 and a `group by` clause to aggregate them:

```
SELECT   role, COUNT(*)
FROM     table
WHERE    assess = 4
GROUP BY role
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That did exactly what I needed.